# sed match variable multiple words

Tags: regex, sed

With this input:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

I have a sed script that produces this output:

```
int main(argc, argv)
int argc; char *argv[];
```

The line matching expression is:

```
/\w\s*\(((\w\s+[*]{0,1}\s*\w+\s*(\[\s*\]){0,1})\s*[,\)]\s*)+/ { block do stuff }
```

/\w\s*
However this fails to match the function construct:

int main(struct mystruct *astruct)

because the type is now composed of two separate words "struct mystruct"

so I changed the initial part of the match to :

```
/\w\s*\((((\w\s+){1,2}[*]{0,1}\s*\w+\s*(\[\s*\]){0,1})\s*[,\)]\s*)+/
```

changing the first '\w\s+' to '(\w\s+){1,2}'.

But this matches nothing! neither 1 or two type words.

Not sure what the solution is here or why '(\w\s+){1,2}' doesn't match one or two words followed by spaces.

A simpler expression that shows the issue are :

```
/(\w\s+){1,2}/
```

Which will match two words followed by space.

```
/(\w\s+){1,2}\)/
```

Which will match two words followed by a ' )' and works.

but :

```
/\(\s*(\w\s+){1,2}/
```

which I thought should match '(' followed by two words does not work!

Not sure how I'm misinterpreting this.

Comment: Note that \w match only one single character.  It is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_] (unless non-ASCII unicode is used).  To match a word with multiple characters, you have to use \w+

Comment: Dude submit your reply as the answer that was the problem.  It was never matching words as my testing thought.  It was just matching the last character in a word!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `\w` with `\w+` since `\w` matches only one single character. It is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_] (unless non-ASCII unicode is used). To match a word with multiple characters, you have to use `\w+`

Your regex can be fine-tuned as follows:

```
/\w+\s*\((((\w+\s+){1,2}\*?\s*\w+\s*(\[\s*\])?)\s*[,\)]\s*)+/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TMM0vk/1)

Amendments as follows:

1. replaced `\w` with `\w+`
2. replaced `{0,1}` with `?`  (to be more succinct)
3. replaced `[*]` with `\*`  (to be more succinct)

Anyway, the regex may still need further fine-tuning for it to work with more generic syntax e.g.  with empty parameter.   If you just want to match the 2 particular samples, it should work fine now.

### Edit

Further fine-tuned to support empty parameter as well as more than 2 parameters (in addition to 1 or 2 parameters.  Thus, any number of parameters)

```
/\w+\s*\(((\s*(\w+\s+){1,2}\*?\s*\w+\s*(\[\s*\])?)\s*)?(,(\s*(\w+\s+){1,2}\*?\s*\w+\s*(\[\s*\])?))*\)/
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZcaNkl/1)